# applying VAT Rule in magento

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, magento

when i started on magento i use to list items including VAT as i am not VAT register. but now i have automated my price and data from a data supply company. and they send prices exclude VAT so i needed a rule to add 20% VAT on top of them.

i have created a rule as told here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-value-added-tax-vat
and gave it Name "Standard VAT" but the problem is my magento is using attribute for tax "Taxable" and not using "VAT Standard"

can you tell me how to make magento use this rule by default? and show the prices include VAT on front end, every where.

there is a solution to select all the item in catalog and edit attribute and select "Standard VAT" but that is not fault proof. we edit new items every day and wont find a out which product is showing VAT and which isnt.

another thing i have done is: changed the setting in "taxable" attribute. but it is still not showing VAT on front end. i have tried to give priority to "standard VAT2 but no use.

you help will be much appreciated. please tell every thing in little details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have setup your Product Tax Rules which will have all the countries and rates you want to apply assigned to your Standard VAT Product VAT class, you will then to change each product to use this tax class. Go into the product, select prices, and change the VAT class to Standard VAT. Providing your rules are all setup correctly and you have set in the system configuration that your product prices are now setup as excluding tax, then it will automatically apply your tax rules to the products on the frontend.

I am unaware of a Default System Configuration Option for product tax_class_id. Ultimately it is simply an EAV attribute like any other custom product attribute. My deployment always defaults to the first product tax class after None when setting up a new product. What you could do is go into the database manually and set the default value of the tax_class_id attribute to be the ID of the product tax class you want to default to. Something like the following would probably do it;

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `default_value` = '2' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`='tax_class_id';
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. but do you know how to make that rule apply for all products by default? like when ever we add a new product it auto use that rule?

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply, can you tell me the path please?

Comment: ? Path to what? Just connect to the database and execute the above SQL on your magento database. Change the default_value = 2 to what ever the ID is of the tax class you want set as default. If your unsure get someone who knows what they are doing to do this for you.

Comment: Hi, Path to the data base file where i can edit that code? sorry i dont have any developer to work for me. if you can tell the file location that would be so great of you like: app>code>code>default>

Comment: Databases don't work like that. I highly suggest you employ a developer who knows what he is doing.

Comment: i dont know any developer who can work on this? can you?

Comment: Hi Ashley,can you tell me how to find that "default_value = 2"

Comment: Hi Ashley, thank you for the code above, it works but the only problem is, it dont work with imported products. if i list item privately it has auto selected the attribute, but when uploading the big file for inventory, it still dont have that attribute selected. any solution? Thanks